# DataTables get field headers based on input json object

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to create a DataTables object from a json object (following [this](https://datatables.net/manual/data/) example).  I can assume the input is an array of objects, each with the same set of keys.

I want to create a table that gets its column headers dynamically from the first row of the input.

See my js function below

```
 function populateDataTable(json_obj) {
/*extract fields from ajax return*/
var columns_obj = [];
for (var key in json_obj[0]) {
  columns_obj.push({
    'data': key
  })
}
console.log(columns_obj);

/*draw html table container*/
var html_table = '<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr>';
for (var i = 0; i < columns_obj.length; i++) {
  html_table += '<th>' + columns_obj[i]['data'] + '</th>';
}
html_table += '<tr></thead></table>';
console.log(html_table);
$('#query_output').html(html_table);
console.log('columns_obj:', columns_obj.length, 'ajax data length:', Object.keys(json_obj[0]).length);
console.log($('#query_output th').length);
alert('pause');
$('#query_output table').DataTable({
  data: json_obj,
  columns: columns_obj
});
```

}

In my fiddle here, contrary to my expectation the data is assigned entirely to a single field header 'name'.  Be warned that running this messes with the sandboxing of the fiddle.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mosarani/yp1hLw1L/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I let data tables do a little more work than you and came up with this:

http://jsbin.com/zeminu/edit?html,js,console,output

```
    $(function () {

        /* user  run query click event*/
        $('#run_query').click(function () {
            populateDataTable(sample_ajax);
        });

        function populateDataTable(json_obj) {
            console.log(json_obj)
            /*extract fields from ajax return*/
            var keys = Object.keys(json_obj[0]);
            var columns_obj = [];
            $.each(keys, function (i, it) {
                columns_obj[i] = { data: it, title: it };
            });


            /*draw html table container*/
            var html_table = '<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';

            $('#query_output').html(html_table);

            $('#query_output table').DataTable({
                data: json_obj,
                columns: columns_obj
            });
        }
    });
```